# (Why) does having a directive that "calls itself" in a finite ng-repeat lead to a stack overflow from infinite recursion?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recursion, angular-directive

EDIT: See [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hIIiGqXU8Nsklu0ftQqG?p=preview) for a simplified version of the problem (an [sscce](http://sscce.org/)).

---

The following code seems to cause an infinite recursion problem:

**statement.directive.html**

```
<textarea></textarea><br />
<button ng-click='statement.newStatement()'>New Statement</button>
<button ng-click='statement.newSubstatement()'>New Substatement</button>
<hr />
<statement
  ng-repeat='statement in statement.curr.sections'
  curr='statement'
  parent='statement.curr'>
</statement>
```

I don't know why though. `statement.curr.sections` is zero (when I tested it). So wouldn't that directive not get "instantiated/implemented"?

---

```
<p ng-repeat='statement.curr.sections'>x</p>
```

Doesn't cause any problems.

Wrapping it in an `ng-if` doesn't fix the problem.

```
<div ng-if='statement.curr.sections > 0'>
  <statement
    ng-repeat='statement in statement.curr.sections'
    curr='statement'
    parent='statement.curr'>
  </statement>
</div>
```

Edit: this doesn't work either (but I realize I chose bad variable names).

```
<textarea></textarea><br />
<hr />
<statement
  ng-repeat='item in statementCtrl.curr.sections'>
</statement>
```

Code on [GitHub](https://github.com/adamzerner/simulated-selves).

Comment: Don't name your child and parent variable with the same string: `statement in statement`. What happens when you try: `item in statement` instead?

Comment: @ngDeveloper see the edit to my post. Awesome username though!

Comment: Can you prepare a plunker

Comment: @PSL I'm working on it. The site seems to be down though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at your github code but it's really confusing. The naming is definitely throwing my brain in circles, so I would start by clarifying that.

For a directive, you should use a prefix so that it's clear you're referencing a directive: ie. myStatements, elStatement, whatever.

For a service and controller, use a suffix: StatementService, StatementController.

What I don't understand:

```
<button ng-click='statement.newStatement()'>New Statement</button>
```

What is `statement.` referring to here? When does this become initialized/binded to the view? Edit: nevermind I see that's the controller.

OK, so you've got the template for the directive, referencing the directive itself...

Hmm, not sure if a directive can have a child directive that is itself. Seems like quite the infinite loop when the template is trying to render. Because even if the next layer/directive doesn't have data, it still needs to bootstrap the directive and its template, so that leads it to load the next directive... and it never finishes.

Seems like an anti-pattern. What is the use case? Are you trying to draw a fractal? lol

In terms of fractals, you need to pass a limit (ie. when a fractal becomes so small you can't see it, there's no longer a point to draw it). So by imposing some limit, you can stop it from infinitely trying to draw.

**tl;dr:** Even if the data is empty, the child directive is still being initialized/rendered.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about the bad naming. I'll have to fix it. The `statement` in `statement.newStatement()` is referring to the view model (the controller as). What I'm trying to do is allow a user to have write nested statements that are collapsable.

Comment: @AdamZerner Seems like you can do that with a single directive, using StatementService to store an object representing all parent/child nested statements as an array or object. Then it's just a matter of when user clicks "Reply" (or "Add Child"), passing that index/key to the form as a field as the parent, so the form knows where to inject the new statement as a child, under the parent, into the Service object. You then just need to redraw the statement list, by passing the new updated object down to the ng-repeat, when the Submit button is clicked.